# how to replace a line containing certain string with a new modified line with python?

Tags: python, string

My input is:

```
*PART, NAME=Part-Default
**
****************************** N O D E S *********************************
*NODE, NSET=ALLNODES
   1,    2.228570e-02,   -8.715290e-01
   2,    1.463382e-02,   -9.181792e-01
*INSTANCE, NAME=Part-Default_1, PART=Part-Default
*END INSTANCE
```

I want to replace all the fields with Part-Default or Part-Default_1 with Part-1.

Output should be:

```
*PART, NAME=Part-1
**
****************************** N O D E S *********************************
*NODE, NSET=ALLNODES
   1,    2.228570e-02,   -8.715290e-01
   2,    1.463382e-02,   -9.181792e-01
*INSTANCE, NAME=Part-1, PART=Part-1
*END INSTANCE
```

What I propose:

```
lines = f.readlines()
i=0
while (i<len(lines)):
    temp=lines[i].strip().split(',')
    if (temp[1]=="NAME=Part-Default"):
        f.write(""temp"\n")
        temp[1]="NAME=Part-1"
    if (temp[1]=="NAME=Part-1_1"):
        temp[1]="NAME=Part-1"
        f.write(""temp"\n")
    if (temp[2]=="NAME=Part-Default"):
        temp[1]="NAME=Part-1"
        f.write(""temp"\n")
    else
        f.write(""temp"\n")
```

I am not sure about the writing commands. May be we can directly replace the strings somehow. 
regards

Comment: @Paulo, I did not know how to indent.. I clicked tab and each time it got out of that mode.. totally new here.

Comment: Use 4 spaces. Always. Personally, I hate few things more than I hate Python code indented with tabs (God forbid mixed tabs and spaces). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a regular expression replacement on the whole file. You won't need to do this line-by-line unless you are dealing with truly huge files.

```
import re

filename = "xxx.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
new_content = re.sub(r"(\w+)=Part-(1(_1)?|Default(_1)?)", r"\1=Part-1", content)
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(new_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line.replace("Part-Default_1", "Part-1").replace("Part-Default", "Part-1")
```

That will replace ANY instance of Part-Default_1.  If you want to be more specific then you can use something like:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.find("$QUALIFIER"):
        line.replace("Part-Default_1", "Part-1").replace("Part-Default", "Part-1")
```

Make sure you change $QUALIFER to be something that will qualify which lines you want the replace done on.

Comment: Part-Default would not be replaced

Comment: I think the test `"$QUALIFIER" in line` is more idiomatic than `line.find("$QUALIFIER")` in Python. Any advantage over the `.find` method?

Comment: Paulo, can you write more code out?  I'm not sure how you would use `"$QUALIFIER" in line` in the way you suggest.

Comment: Hammad, I fixed it to replace both.